# Calculating the integrated prediction error curve

Tags: survival, model-evaluation, concordance

I am reading Tutz & Schmid ["Modeling Discrete Time-to-Event Data"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) (2016) chapter 4 Evaluation and Model Choice section 4.3.2 Prediction Error Curves. Integrated prediction error curve is defined as
$$
\widehat{\text{PE}}_{\text{int}} = \hat{\mathbb{E}}_T[\widehat{\text{PE}}(T)]=\sum_t \widehat{\text{PE}}(t)\cdot\hat P(T=t).
$$
How is $\hat P$ obtained?

- Is it a fitted value from the model? If the notation were used consistently, that would likely be that. However, the probabilities from the  model are functions of individual-specific covariates, and that would probably not make much sense here.
- Or is it calculated as the proportion of $T=t$ among all $T$s? In such a case, do we calculate it on the training subset or the test subset?
- Or is it something else?

The same question applies to the estimated global concordance index that employs $\hat P$:
$$
\hat{C}^* = \frac{ \sum_t \{ \widehat{\text{AUC}}(t) \cdot \hat P(T=t) \cdot \hat P(T>t) \} }{ \sum_t \{ \hat P(T=t) \cdot \hat P(T>t) \} }.
$$